# how to use jquery validation plugin to view the label specific message at the top?

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate, overriding

I am using jquery validation plugin to display error message in the top instead instead of beside the labels.  say, i have address , city, zip code ....if user don't enter anything i have to display the error message at top in a div like " please enter valid address" , "please enter valid city" etc...
how can I override the default behavior of the plugin .....any help will be appreciated ...
thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`errorLabelContainer` and `wrapper` options](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions) for this:

```
$("form").validate({
  errorLabelContainer: "#someElementUpTop", //a <ul> element for example
  wrapper: "li" //display them in a list
});
```

`errorLabelContainer` determines where the error elements are added, `wrapper` determines what they're wrapped in.  In this case `#someElementUpTop` is a `<ul>` to append the `<li>` wrapped labels to...so clicking still goes to the correct element in the page that has the validation error.  If you need *another* element above this, say a `<div>` that hides and shows appropriately when there are/aren't errors, add a `errorContainer: "#someDiv"` option as well.

Comment: Thanks! Nick do you have any sample ...because I am using the same approach but problem is that I bind blur event ...When I am tab through the textboxes all invalid entry were stack up and when I enter the valid entry that messages were gone but still showing that div ....

Comment: @paul - did you give that `<div>` something you can select and set that selector as the `errorContainer` like in the answer above? That should he hiding/showing it depending on if there are any errors left.  There's a demo page here for a full example: http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/errorcontainer-demo.html

Comment: I had an exception on line errorLabelContainer: "#someElementUpTop" . Changing this to errorLabelContainer: $("#someElementUpTop") worked.